# chrome.storage.sync.set a key in object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an object saved as `obj` in chrome.storage.sync:  `chrome.storage.sync.set({loadingList: {}});` - *and yes, it has to start empty, because of the same reason I have to add the 'a' as a variable (down below)*

So I want to add a key called `a`, and set it to `true`, and if it already exists, then change it's value to `true`.

---

I tried this;

```
let key = "a";
chrome.storage.sync.set({obj[key]: true});
```

> btw I have to save the 'a' as a variable, since it can change, so I can't just say 'obj.a'

but it didn't work, and it put a little red line under the `[` and sayed; `',' expected.`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @wOxxOm I have just edited my post, hope it is more clear now

Comment: So as you can see when inspecting the storage your value is saved under `loadingList` key. To modify the contents of this value you need to read the entire value, modify its properties, save the entire value under the same `loadingList` key.

Comment: I think you want `{obj: { [key]: true } }` though that will lose any other keys set. You really want to set `obj[key] = true` in a separate line, and then save `obj`